# How to calculate fractional differences of a timeseries?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, time-series, finite-difference-method

I have a timeseries I am looking to transform with fractional differences per the following description:

[image]

The idea being to retain the essence of stationarity of, say, a log transformed integer series while preserving some of the 'memory' present in the levels of the values in the original series.

I can code this up manually but wondering what the more direct route might be within WL / Mathematica -- preferably via 'first class' functions within the language. Any advice greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

For sake of a reproducible and fun example for the community, let's assume I want the fractional differences of a financial timeseries object

```
levels = QuantityMagnitude@FinancialData["SPY",{2020,1,1}]
```

The stationary transform is trivial:

```
logTransform = Differences@Log@levels
```

How would I obtain the fractional differences of `levels` rather than the simple log transform? Assume a `d` value of .4

**SECOND EDIT**

This github repo https://github.com/simaki/fracdiff nails the implementation in Python where the following plot is produced:

[image]

Underlying source here: https://github.com/simaki/fracdiff/blob/main/fracdiff/fracdiff.py

Really just trying to figure out what the first-class implementation of this in WL would use!

Comment: Try: Series[(1 - b)^d, {b, 0, 5}]

Comment: Thanks for this. I've added a little contextual example to the question. If you can apply your comment to a full answer for this additional context, I will gladly award you the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Series[(1 - b)^d, {b, 0, 5}]

[image]

Comment: I'd very interested as well for answer to this question.