# How To Implement Discrete Fractional Differentiation in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, time-series, finite-difference-method

This question was borne out of my attempt to answer this question. [How to calculate fractional differences of a timeseries?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241843/how-to-calculate-fractional-differences-of-a-timeseries)

[image]

To recreate this in Matheamatica I wrote this code

```
fracDiff[list_, d_, order_] := Drop[Table[Sum[Binomial[d, k]*(-1)^(k)*(list[[pos - k]] /. List -> 0), {k, 0, 
 order}], {pos, 1, Length[list]}], 1]
```

Where I act on each element of a list using elements prior to it. This code passes the sanity check for d=0 and d=1. However, I can't seem to recreate the results here from this Python package.

https://github.com/fracdiff/fracdiff

[image]

Instead, I get this

```
test = QuantityMagnitude[Normal[
FinancialData["SP500", 
  "AdjustedClose", {{2000, 1, 1}, {2020, 1, 1}}]["Values"]]];
```

[image]

If anyone can help me figure out where I went wrong, I appreciate it very much.

Comment: I just found a relevant chapter Advances in Financial Machine Learning. When I figure it out, I'll post it here if no else does it before me.

Comment: There are the built-ins [`FractionalD`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FractionalD.html) and [`CaputoD`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CaputoD.html), and the resource function [`FractionalD`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FractionalD). Do any of those help?

Comment: Aren't those just for continuous functions and not time series. I suppose I can always use interpolation. After I implement the above, I'll see how that compares with the new fractional differentiation functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can observe that the fractional difference of a time series element $X_i$ (denote $\mathcal{D}X_i$) is basically the inner product of the vector $\{X_i,\dots,X_2,X_1\}$ and the vector $\{\binom{d}{0},-\binom{d}{1},\dots,(-1)^{i-1}\binom{d}{i-1}\}$. Thus, the series $\mathcal{D}X_i$ is *a convolution* of the original series with the infinite kernel $\mathcal{K}=\{\binom{d}{0},-\binom{d}{1},\dots,(-1)^{i-1}\binom{d}{i-1},\dots\}$.

Mathematically speaking, we need infinitely many elements in our original list: a fractional difference of a list of finitely many terms has to be truncated at the order that precisely matches the number of terms causally available. In other words, if we have a list of 10 elements, the fractional difference of the leading term is truncated at order 9 whereas the fractional difference of the last term is truncated at order 0 (no past term to compute difference).

The way we implement this is that we *pad* our original list with *infinitely many zeros* in the past: taking the convolution of this infinite list with the infinite kernel $\mathcal{K}$ is equivalent to the truncated fractional difference.

In mathematica, there is a built-in function to take convolutions of any list: `ListConvolve[kernel,list,1,0]`. The 1 refers to the alignment of the kernel with the list, and the 0 is the padding that we mentioned above. The only difference is that the kernel has to be a finite list: as long as we truncate it with a length equal to or greater than that of the list, the answer is the same (and what we are after).

`ListConvolve` already works with `TimeSeries`, so let us keep things compact:

```
test = FinancialData["SP500","AdjustedClose", {{2000, 1, 1}, {2020, 1,1}}];
kernel[d_] := kernel[d] = With[{order = Length@Normal[test]}, 
                   Table[(-1)^k Binomial[d, k], {k, 0, order - 1}]];
```

Let us define a helper plot function:

```
plot[derivative_, range_, color_, ticks_] := DateListPlot[ListConvolve[kernel[derivative], test, 1, 0], 
    PlotRange -> range, PlotStyle -> {Thin, color}, ImageSize -> Large,
    Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> ticks, ImagePadding -> 30];
```

We can then plot and see the result:

```
Overlay[{
  plot[0, {500, 3500}, Blue, {{All, None}, {All, All}}],
  plot[1/2, {-250, 300}, Orange, {{None, All}, {All, All}}]
}]
```

[image: graph]

**A few remarks:** Clearly, this is *not exactly* what the Python code shows. There may be many reasons for that; nevertheless, the main culprit would be our choice of truncation: we truncated the fractional difference at the maximum order possible for each term: this means that the right side of the graph is evaluated at higher orders than the left side. The extreme is the leftmost value: it is evaluated at zeroth order, which is the original value $X_1$ itself. This is precisely why we observe the spike at the left. However, this is a mathematical limitation, not a programming one.

**Bonus:** It would visually make much more sense if we were to pass our data through a low-pass filter. This is readily available in Mathematica via the command `LowpassFilter`, which we can use with four different difference values $\left(0,1/40,1/10,1/2\right)$ to observe the expected continuous change:

```
filtered[n_] := LowpassFilter[ListConvolve[kernel[n], test, 1, 0], 10^{-6}];
DateListPlot[Table[filtered[i], {i, {0, 1/40, 1/10, 1/2}}], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: graph2]